# Which robot can or should I get to run ROS?

Tags: ros, hardware, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've heard a lot of good things about ROS and I want to try running it.

PR2 is a little too expensive to me though. Is there anything more afordable to give ROS a try?
What is the best use of my money?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9072/which-robot-can-or-should-i-get-to-run-ros?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that if you want to try running ROS you don't really need robot hardware. The cheapest option costs no money at all - It's running a robot in simulation. There are quite a few robot models available for doing that. I can recommend the 'erratic_robot' stack, which provides a differential driven robot that you can use to drive around in gazebo simulation.
It of course always depends on your focus, but for playing around, understanding basic concepts of navigation, the coordinate frame conventions etc. this is a very good option.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many robots using ROS.  See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots

For a learning platform something like the Create or Rovio might be a good place to start.  There are several projects working to build up the user experience on the create such as http://www.bilibot.com/ coming soon.

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what you want to try with ROS, you can start with a relatively basic platform.  I think that the main requirements for this platform (in order to be able to fully appreciate ROS) would be:

- Locomotion: Some way of moving around in an environment.  As Tully suggests, an iRobot Create is a good approach.  You may also roll-your-own.  Generally, if you design your own platform, you will have to write your own nodes to interface with the motors, rather than relying on previously-written stacks.  A suggestion, though, encoders (or some sort of odometry) are more or less a must for navigation applications.
- Computation: A (somewhat portable) computer that is capable of running ROS.  There are plenty of solutions for this from a single board computer up to a full motherboard (or servers like the PR2!).  Computation power is typically determined by how much you want to do.  You can play with some of the ROS nodes on your computer to get a feel for what size computer you will need (and then buy bigger!)
- Sensing:  In order to do navigation and SLAM, you will need some way to see your environment around you.  The Kinect has really revolutionized this part, mainly because of the price point.  Other sensors are available, such as laser range finders (not cheap), or webcam inputs.

For basic navigation, mapping, and SLAM work, this should be enough to whet your appetite.  As you move to more advanced concepts (such as arm motion planning), you may need more advanced hardware, but this will cover a wide variety of topics.

As an aside, I have essentially described the [Bilibot](http://www.bilibot.com/) that @Tully linked to in his answer, just letting you know that other options are also available.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2014-09-12**:
FYI, Bilibot is officially dead.